# exposing soap as rest service in java

Tags: java, web-services

I have a vendor web service which is in SOAP but I have to write a wrapper class and expose it as Rest. Is it possible??

it will be something like client will call Rest Service but internally rest service will call Soap service.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, and quite common actually. Writing middleware/glue/wrapper code is done all the time.

The approach I would take is to generate the client code using your vendors web service WSDL - for example using Axis wsdl2java. This generated code can be put into it's own lib/jar. Then write your own REST code using whatever framework you want that leverages the lib you created.

Clients would call your REST service which would internally use the lib code to connect to your vendors web service.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Protocol Bridging SOA Patternis used to transform between different protocols by using a bridging broker as intermediary. The broker holds the transformation logic. bridges are available in most ESBs and EAI middle-wares.

http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/protocol_bridging

2) Write your own logic adopter read Soap request convert in your code and expose as rest .